# How to slice a float from between 2 strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string like below. The numbers will have varying lengths so I need to extract the numbers between the 2 strings.

```
<CST, 49.64644, 64.72381, 114.3702>
```

I want to be able to extract the numbers into an array like below:

```
x = [49.64644, 64.72381, 114.3702]
```

Comment: Is the string always starting and ending with a well-defined head/tail like ``<CST`` and ``>`` in your example?

Comment: you can use regex `([\d.]+)`  it will select only digits

Comment: Have you tried splitting string on "," ? Check out [examples](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html).

Comment: Are the "float" actually decimal literals (as in digits around a dot) or float literals (including e.g. ``3.14e-10`` or ``3.14_15_93``)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Thanks to Abhishek**

Answer:

```
import re
import numpy as np

c = '<CST, 49.64644, 64.72381, 114.3702>'
x = np.array(re.findall("([\d.]+)", c))
x = [float(i) for i in x]
```

Returns:

```
[49.64644, 64.72381, 114.3702]
```